# 2012 SSIS package behaving different from one environment to another

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

We have a 2012 SSIS package developed on a development VM that runs successfully end to end both in VS 2010 and via Integration Services Catalog on 2012 Server. When we run the very same SSIS package on a staging VM which has identical image as our dev VMs it fails on various tasks. The only differences between the 2 VMs is the servers we are pointing in our connection managers. However, the issue is not related to endpoints or data but how SSIS actually runs the tasks. In several of our data flow tasks we are using OLE DB Source component and use a Sql Command which requires parameters. In all our queries we put comment headers. On our dev VMs this works fine....no issues.  When run from the a staging VM it cannot parse the query to determine the parameters.  Another example is from an Execute SQL Component we are pulling the `@@DBTS` and casting it as bigint (i.e. `SELECT CAST(@@DBTS AS bigint)`). This is being placed into an SSIS variable (CurrentTimeStamp) of string type. We then pass it to another Execute SQL Component which calls a stored procedure which takes the variable (CurrentTimeStamp) but in the parameter mapping we pass the input as LONG data type.  Again this works fine in our dev VMs but not in the staging VM. We receive an error the following error: “An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I4)”.  Possible failure reasons: Problems with query. “ResultSet”   property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

I've compared OS versions, patches and software installed.  With the only differences listed below:

- Dev VM Staging VM
- Missing    Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 - ENU v10.0.40219
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.3.0729.4148    Missing
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.3.0729.4148    Missing
- Missing    Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.3.0729.4974

If anyone else has experienced anything similar any guidance you may provide would be greatly appreciated. Our next step is to open a support ticket with MS as this has just been a head scrather.

Thanks in advance,
Anthony

***Edit...this issue has been resolved.  See summary below.***

Issue 1:

++We had a Execute Sql Task which returns a DB Timestamp value which is stored in a variable of Type LONG. The task works on DEV Server but fails on the PROD Server. In the PROD Server, if we change the SSIS Variable type to ULONG, the task succeeds.

We figured out that in PROD, the return value was a big number causing the LONG data type to overflow. In DEV we had a smaller value and the issue was not happening. I researched and checked that ULONG maximum value boils down to UInt64.MaxValue which is pretty huge and  should suffice to your requirement. (The maximum value is: 18,446,744,073,709,551,615)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint64.maxvalue.aspx

Issue 2:

++We had an OLE DB Source which fires a Sql Command. If we put comments on top of the query, it works on DEV Server but fails validation while parsing on the PROD Server with the error:
Parameters cannot be extracted from the SQL command. The provider might not help to parse parameter information from the command. In that case, use the "SQL command from variable" access mode, in which the entire SQL command is stored in a variable.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

We figured out that the comment parsing ability is actually on the backend query engine where the query is executed and is not SSIS specific. In our DEV, we were firing the query(with comments) against a Sql 2012 instance where it parsed fine. In the failing PROD Server, the query was executing against a Sql 2008 R2 instance which is not able to parse the comments. If we change the connection manager in the PROD to point to Sql 2012 instance and fire the same query with comments, it parses fine.